# The method is undefined for the type JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gir2R7G9ws and copy pasted everything and now I am getting an error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

The script is here, for Window class:

```
package GamePackage;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4882660542739611206L;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSide(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSide(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSide(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();

    }

}
```

And for the Game class:

```
package GamePackage;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;


public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3429322092557125719L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Game () {
        new Window(WIDTH,HEIGHT, "Game Project", this);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try{
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        }catch(Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while(running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running)
                render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick() {

    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    private static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

For Window class, I get this error:

```
The method is undefined for the type JFrame
```

What am I missing in order to make this script to work?

Comment: This may be a problem: `private static void main`. That must be public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code! You have to write:

```
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

instead of Side. So you basically wrote a "d" instead of "z".

Comment: import GamePackage.Game

Comment: or just do GamePackage.*

Comment: It will still execute the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method setPreferredSide(Dimension) is undefined for the type JFrame
 The method setMaximumSide(Dimension) is undefined for the type JFrame
 The method setMinimumSide(Dimension) is undefined for the type JFrame

 at GamePackage.Window.<init>(Window.java:18)
 at GamePackage.Game.<init>(Game.java:18)
 at GamePackage.Game.main(Game.java:87)

Comment: Now I see the typo! I updated my answer above! :) Would have been helpful if you showed the error message earlier :D

Comment: Wow... How can I be this sloppy.. :D In future I will rather recheck the code 50 times instead of 10 times. Thanks alot! :)